# Inspecting STL container not working right

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Since Update 3 of Visual Studio 2015, I have the problem that the Inspector won't show me the informations like the string content of an `std::wstring` in the first place. I had to open the Inspector first to see the string.
I tried to fixed the problem with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656222/inspecting-stl-containers-in-visual-studio-2015) but it don't work.
Also `std::string`, `std::vector<T>`, etc. don't work and only show `{...}`.

Screenshot (Instead of `{...}` there should be something like `L"Hello"`):
[image: Inspector]

Comment: Are you using a `std::string` or `std::wstring`.  `L""` is for wide characters.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm using std::wstring but this problem also happens with std::string. For clarification, I edit it to std::wstring

Comment: And it worked in Update 2?

Comment: @RustyX Yes, worked on Update 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow Visual Studio destroyed itself with the Update 3. I had to reinstall the English Language Pack and set it in Visual Studio (before it was German and there was no option for English). Now it works.

Related: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1676171/change-in-c-stl-container-implementation-causes-debug-visualizer-error