# Visual studio 2015 doesn't show content of vector in c++ in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Visual studio 2015 update 3 doesn't show content of vector in c++ in debug mode (it shows three point instead). I tried following:
1. Repair visual studio. (although I had vs 2015 update 3 initially)
2. Checked if this regkey set correctly:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/36341387/5933861
3. Checks 'Use managed compatibility mode' and 'Use native compatibility mode' are both unckecked.
How to enable this quite basic functionality in VS 2015?

Comment: Solved by full uninstallation in force mode and following installation from the scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I set up another language pack and then recovered it again. Then it is solved.