# VS2015 Debugger is not expanding variables

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015

When I debug a c++ application, I am unable to see the value of the variable
If you see below,

```
std::string s = "a";
```

The debugger only shows the value as {...}, even if I extend the value.

What I have tried

- Deleted the symbol cache, (Tools > Options ... > Debugging > Symbols.
- Unchecked "Use Managed Compatibility mode"
- Checked "Use Managed Compatibility Mode"
- Unchecked "Use Native Compatibility Mode"
- Checked "Use Native Compatibility Mode"
- I have tried to export the settings from the working environment and then import them into the other one, with no luck.

Any suggestions? ...

[image: VS2015 debugger]

I get the same issue with `std::vector<std::string> ...` or any other type, I cannot expand the data.

**Edit**: Added a picture of what it is *supposed* to look like ...

[image: What it should look like]

**Edit 2**: I have tried to export the settings from the working environment and then import them into the other one, with no luck.

Comment: It's there on the line you highlight.  You need to expand the `_Myval2` node a few levels.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the way it is supposed to work. If you have a `std::vector<string> ...` you have to expand about 10 levels per values, (as an example). The debugger does not normally work that way.

Comment: How did you get the "supposed to look like" picture? From a release build? I'm guessing that the debug version of the CRT has a bunch of complexity in it to help you catch bugs, and that's messing up the debugger visualizer. I can't remember which view I see in Visual Studio; I'm not near a computer with it installed at the moment.

Comment: This was taken from another dev machine. Neither versions are release build, both are running the exact same code in debug, (same breakpoint, same steps followed), hence the reason I think it must be an environment setting rather than a project setting.

Comment: @FFMG, I test it in my side, it works well in VS2015 with update 3 in windows 10:https://1drv.ms/i/s!Auvjmr9ZOuhVhwpUEA18h9fHrdoo. I just use the default VS settings(C#), if the same app works well in other VS machine, I suggest you repair your VS. Please also install the latest update 3. Actually I didn't select two options "Use Managed/Native Compatibility mode", in project property I select the "Auto" debugging type. Actually I met this issue before which was related to the VS setup up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656222/inspecting-stl-containers-in-visual-studio-2015.

Comment: @FFMG, Does it still have this issue now?

Comment: I fixed it by un-installing and re-installing vs2015, but I cannot say what was the actual issue to start with, all I know is that it was fixed after a re-install. The only thing I know is that I had the early release of VS2015 so maybe the subsequent updates that did fix the debug issues, (Update 3?), did not fix it if you had an early release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the issue I un-installed VS2015 completely, (including all the updates and other "vs2015" tools that were installed over the months.

I then ran ccleaner a couple of times to remove dead registry settings left behind, (not sure if that helped, but it doesn't hurt).

I than re-ran the install, it picked up that update 3 was needed.

A couple of things were not removed as I didn't need to re-register and enter my credentials.
But it seems it wasn't the problem as the re-install did the trick.

Also:

- Unchecked "Use Managed Compatibility mode"
- Unchecked "Use Native Compatibility Mode"